# Can generic type hints like Dict and List be used bare, without square brackets?

Tags: python, type-hinting

The docs on [`Dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Dict) show it being used as a generic type, like this:

```
def get_position_in_index(word_list: Dict[str, int], word: str) -> int:
    return word_list[word]
```

It would also, of course, be correct to type-hint `word_list` above as `dict`:

```
def get_position_in_index(word_list: dict, word: str) -> int:
    return word_list[word]
```

But is it correct to use `Dict` as a type-hint on its own to indicate a `dict` with keys and values of any type, like this?

```
def get_position_in_index(word_list: Dict, word: str) -> int:
    return word_list[word]
```

(And likewise, can other generic types like `List` and `Sequence` be used bare in this way?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `Dict` is considered to be an alias for `Dict[Any, Any]`. (And `dict` is also an alias for `Dict[Any, Any]`).

This is the case for any generic type, whether it's a builtin one or a custom-made one: if you omit the type parameters, they always default to `Any`. This is specified in the [*Generics* section of PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#generics) (emphasis added):

> Additionally, `Any` is a valid value for every type variable. Consider the following:
>
> ```
> def count_truthy(elements: List[Any]) -> int:
>     return sum(1 for elem in elements if element)
> ```
>
> ***This is equivalent to omitting the generic notation and just saying `elements: List`.***

That said, I think the general recommendation is that you should fully write out `Dict[Any, Any]` instead of using just `Dict` -- [explicit is better then implicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), and so forth.

The only downside is that your function type signatures are now longer. But we can work around that by using type aliases:

```
from typing import Dict, Any

AnyDict = Dict[Any, Any]
WordDict = Dict[str, int]

# Equivalent to your first code sample
def get_position_in_index_1(word_list: WordDict, word: str) -> int:
    return word_list[word]

# Equivalent to your second and third code samples
def get_position_in_index_2(word_list: AnyDict, word: str) -> int:
    return word_list[word]
```